# Restoring From Another Dev's MDF on Same Database: MDF Cannot be Overwritten

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the situation:

We have multiple developers. We want to import/export(restore/backup) `.bak` files whilst working on the same, but local, databases(Each dev has a local instance of DB: A).

The problem is as follows:

I try to do a `BACKUP DATABASE` and generate a `.bak`. The other dev receives this `.bak` and tries to `RESTORE DATABASE` using the `MOVE` statements to change to paths of the `.mdf`/`.ldf`'s as they might be different. The problem is that it will complain about the `.mdf`/`.ldf`'s being unoverwriteable, even though they are from the same database as the `.bak`.

Is there a way to do what we want? It has to be done through `sqlcmd`. It would also be a plus if we can have the `.bak` not replace the database but rather "merge" with it.

We are using MS SQL Express 2008 R2.

If any additional information is needed, just ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Posting the exact statement and error message that your attempted restore generated would be helpful. My guess is that adding `with replace` will fix it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a temporary permissions issue and logging out and back in "fixed" it.

Answer (score -1):

I logged off and back on and it seems to no longer throw the error.

Comment: It is okay. If you would explain the reasons for the googlers of the future, you would probably get some upvotes, too.